# how to sort files during processing in Java

Tags: java, maven

I am quiet new to Java and during processing i found that the files has been processed randomly without any order.

I want to sort the files by date such that it can process sequencly. There has been few functions in java which can does that but dont know exactly where i need to place it.

```
public class OMapping extends AbstractWorkflow {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OMapping.class);
    private WorkflowEnvironment workflowEnvironment;

    @Override
    public boolean run(CommandLine commandLine) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = initializeApplicationContext();

        String in = commandLine.getOptionValue("in");
        String done = commandLine.getOptionValue("doneDir");
        if (in == null) {
            LOG.error("The input directory has not been specified");
            return false;
        }
        if(done == null){
             LOG.error("The done directory has not been specified");
            return false;
        }

        Path indir = Paths.get(in);
        Path doneDir = Paths.get(done);
        MappingFileImporter oMappingFileImporter = applicationContext.getBean(oMappingFileImporter.class);

        LOG.info("Importing files from " + in);
        Files.walk(indir, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .filter(f -> f.getFileName().toString().matches("OFFENE_LIEFERORDERS.*\\.csv"))
                .forEach(f -> {
                    try {
                        oMappingFileImporter.importFile(f);
                        Path moved = Files.move(f.toAbsolutePath(), doneDir.resolve(f.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                    }
                });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "orderidmappingimporter";
    }

    @Override
    public void addOptions(Options options) {
        options.addOption(null, "in", true,
                "(orderidmappingimporter) specifies the input directory");
        options.addOption(null, "doneDir", true,
                "(orderidmappingimporter) specifies the done directory");
    }   

}
```

Comment: Why does order matter? You could use forEachOrdered instead of forEach to force it to compute it in order of the list.

Comment: So it is sorted by name but not by date, you should claryfie that in your question!
You could use the .sorted() method and write your own comperator but you would need to get the creation date from the "Path"

Comment: Why should it sort by date if you do not tell it to?

Comment: sorry i edited my question updated with sort by date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort those Files by date. The method `Files.walk()` will return `Stream<Path>` and it will be sorted by the name and not the date, it doesn't even have the date as the values are paths.
You can use the `.sorted()` method with a comparator to sort after last modified:

```
            Files.walk(indir, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(p -> p.toFile().lastModified()))
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

This uses the Comparator class to compare the long value returned by `.lastModified()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--

Comment: thanks its working with the date now...just small question if i want to sort by name in future instead of date then only forEachOrdered is sufficient instead of forEach and i will also not need sorted ?

Comment: forEachOrdered will follow the order of the list/itereater what ever backs up the stream while forEach most of the times runs in order but doesn't have to. So yes i would be enough as long as the implementation of walk doesn't change to be sure you could use a comparator for strings like ".sorted(Path::compareTo)" or ".sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())"

Comment: Simpler and more modern: `Comparator.comparing(Files::getLastModifiedTime​)`.

Answer (score 2):

The method Files.walk returns a Stream of Path (refer [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)), and you can call the 'sorted' method, implementing your own comparator, which lets you sort the stream based on any attribute you want.

You can do something like this if you want to sort the files by creation date:

```
Files.walk(indir, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
 .sorted(
        new Comparator<Path>() {
            public int compare(Path p1, Path p2) {
                return Files.readAttributes(p1, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime().toMillis() -
                            Files.readAttributes(p2, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime().toMillis();
            }
        }
     )
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .filter(f -> f.getFileName().toString().matches("OFFENE_LIEFERORDERS.*\\.csv"))
    .forEachOrdered(f -> {
        try {
            oMappingFileImporter.importFile(f);
            Path moved = Files.move(f.toAbsolutePath(), doneDir.resolve(f.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    });
```

This uses the java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes class, so you should import this at the top of your file.